# Data can't be exported to CSV after tapply and unlist

Tags: r, csv, tapply

I am very new to R, so I apologize if this is a very simple question.  I have data that is structured like this:

```
> head(example)
  id var1
1  1    a
2  1    b
3  1    c
4  2    x
5  2    y
6  3    f
>
```

I want to collapse it down so there is just one observation per id, like so:

```
  id    var1 
 1    a, b, c 
 2    x, y 
 3    f
```

So after much searching and experimenting and reading through similar examples, I find that I can achieve this using the following:

```
new <-tapply(example$var1, example$id, unlist)
```

I view the data, and it looks almost like I expect it to:
[it turned id into row.names and var1 into x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMgQd.jpg)

But, I am thinking that's good enough, so I will export it.  However, whether to csv, text, etc. I always get the same error:

```
Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep, eol,  :
  unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'
```

I have tried `toString(new$x)`, `unlist(new$x)`, `as.character(new$x)`, `paste(new$x)` and several other code snippets, but nothing seems to fix the error.

It seems like, since it is possible for the data to show up in the viewer properly, there should also be a way to force it to export to csv in that format.  Or do I need to go back and change the way I reshaped the data?

Comment: Change your tapply statement to: `tapply(example$var1, example$id, toString)` now the result is an array and not list

Comment: That worked perfectly - thank you so much!  I knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(text=paste(val1, collapse=','))
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I also haven't figured out how to get around my work's security settings, so I can't install packages like tidyverse, etc.  But I will try that as well if/when I figure out a workaround.  Thanks!